Laravel Livewire Categories function affecting another input
I'm trying to get the categories and it's categories as nested items. Following code works, but the problem is when I input minimum price or maximum price value, only parent categories comes up when content changed on the page.
How can I solve this unexpected behavior?
sidebar.blade.php
<div class="bg-white p-6 border border-border-white rounded-md hidden md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-6 md:max-w-[270px] h-fit">
    <div>
       <p class="capitalize font-semibold">type</p>
       <ul class="mt-3 flex flex-col gap-1">
           <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
               <input type="radio" id="any" wire:model="type" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" value="any" wire:click="type">
               <label for="any" class="capitalize">any</label>
           </li>
           <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
               <input type="radio" id="auction" wire:model="type" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" value="auction" wire:click="type">
               <label for="auction" class="capitalize">Auction</label>
           </li>
           <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
               <input type="radio" id="classified" wire:model="type" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" value="classified" wire:click="type">
               <label for="classified" class="capitalize">classified</label>
           </li>
           selected {{$type}}
       </ul>
   </div> 
    <div>
enter code here
       <p class="capitalize font-semibold">category</p>
       <ul class="mt-3 flex flex-col gap-1">
           <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
               <input type="radio" id="any" wire:model="category" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" wire:click="category" value="0">
               <label for="any" class="capitalize">any</label>
           </li>
           @foreach ($categories as $category)
               <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <input type="radio" id="classified" wire:model="category" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" wire:click="category" value="{{ $category->id}}">
                    <label for="classified" class="capitalize">{{ __($category->name) }}</label>
                </li>
                @if(!is_null($category->subcategories))
                <ul class="mt-1 ml-5 flex flex-col gap-1">
                    @foreach ($category->subcategories as $subcategory)
                        <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                            <input type="radio" id="apperal" wire:model="category" class="accent-purple w-4 h-4" wire:click="category" value="{{ $subcategory->id}}">
                            <label for="apperal" class="capitalize">{{ __($subcategory->name) }}</label> 
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                @endif
           @endforeach
       </ul>
   </div>
   <div>
       <p class="capitalize font-semibold">price</p>
       <input type="number" wire:model="min_price" wire:model.live="min_price" id="min_price" placeholder="Min Price" class="mt-3 w-full border border-border-white rounded-md p-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-purple">
       @error('min_price')
            <p class="text-sm mt-1 text-red-500">{{ $message}}</p>
       @enderror
       <input type="number" wire:model="max_price" wire:model.live="max_price" id="max_price" placeholder="Max Price" class="mt-1 w-full border border-border-white rounded-md p-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-purple">
   </div>
</div>

Sidebar.php
    <?php

namespace App\Livewire\Listings;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\Attributes\Url;
use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;

class Sidebar extends Component
{
    #[Url]
    public $type = 'any';

    #[Url]
    public $category = 'any';

    #[Url, Validate]
    public $min_price = '';

    #[Url]
    public $max_price = '';

    public $categories;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->categories = $this->getNestedCategories();
        
    }

    private function getNestedCategories($parentId = null)
    {
        $categories = Category::where('parent_id', $parentId)->get();
        
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $category->subcategories = $this->getNestedCategories($category->id);
        }
        
        return $categories; 
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'min_price' => 'numeric|between:1,999999999',
            'max_price' => 'numeric|between:1,999999999',
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.listings.sidebar', [
            'categories' => $this->categories,
        ]);
    }
}

Category.php
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Status;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function Listings(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function child(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parent(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    protected $casts = [
        'is_active' => Status::class,
    ];
}


The request is not entirely clear.
If you are looking for a way to display in the main section of the page a list based on the selections made in the sidebar you must provide the component that manages the the main section and perhaps the model related to the list.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a way to limit the categories shown in the sidebar, based on the price limits, we can do something.
Since you don't specify where the prices are placed I will assume that they are on the same record of the category.
I see some problems at various levels in your code:

you use a recursive function to get the category rows which, in addition to the overhead caused by recursion, causes you to run into the N+1 query problem. I will use relationships to organize data hierarchically.

In the class you use a public property to store the categories but then you pass it as view parameter. I will remove the public property

In the view you use wire:model together with wire:click applied to the radio buttons: this seems wrong, I will remove wire:click and use wire:model.live

In the view you use wire:model together with wire:live applied to the inputs for the prices: this is not necessary, I will remove wire:model and use wire:model.live.500 to avoid continuous calls to the backend

In the view you don't use wire:key in the lists generated by loops

The same HTML id attribute is used for multiple inputs, this causes when you click on a label that points to the same id the first input that has that id is selected. Furthermore, with Livewire, it is generally not a good practice to assign ids to elements because by reusing the same component multiple times on the page, there would be multiple elements with the same id. To allow labels and inputs to match correctly I will wrap the labels around the inputs, omitting the ids.



The model
To simplify the queries I have defined some scopes. I've also renamed the child relation into children that seems more appropriate
namespace App\Models;

use App\Status;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $casts = [
        'is_active' => Status::class,
    ];


    // This makes it easier to retrieve the main categories
    public function scopeMainCategs (Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->whereNull('parent_id');
    }

    
    // This makes it easier to limit the minimum price
    public function scopeMinPrice (Builder $query, $value): void
    {
        $query->when($value, fn ($q) => $q->where('price', '>=', $value));
    }


    // This makes it easier to limit the maximum price
    public function scopeMaxPrice (Builder $query, $value): void
    {
        $query->when($value, fn ($q) => $q->where('price', '<=', $value));
    }


    // 'child' became 'children'
    public function children(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }


    public function parent(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
 }


The view
<div class="bg-white p-6 border border-border-white rounded-md hidden md:flex md:flex-col md:gap-6 md:max-w-[270px] h-fit">

    <div>

        <p class="capitalize font-semibold">type</p>

        <ul class="mt-3 flex flex-col gap-1">

            <li class="flex items-center gap-2">

                <label class="capitalize">

                    <input type="radio"
                           wire:model.live="type"
                           class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                           value="any"
                    >

                    any

                </label>

            </li>

            <li class="flex items-center gap-2">

                <label class="capitalize">

                    <input type="radio"
                           wire:model.live="type"
                           class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                           value="auction"
                    >

                    Auction

                </label>

            </li>

            <li class="flex items-center gap-2">

                <label  class="capitalize">

                    <input type="radio"
                           wire:model.live="type"
                           class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                           value="classified"
                    >

                    classified

                </label>

            </li>

            selected {{$type}}

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div>

        <p class="capitalize font-semibold">category</p>

        <ul class="mt-3 flex flex-col gap-1">

            <li class="flex items-center gap-2">

                <label class="capitalize">

                    <input type="radio"
                           wire:model.live="category"
                           class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                           value="0"
                    >

                    any

                </label>

            </li>

            @foreach ($categories as $category)

                <li class="flex items-center gap-2" wire:key="catg-list-{{ $category->id }}">

                    <label class="capitalize">

                        <input type="radio"
                               wire:model.live="category"
                               class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                               value="{{ $category->id}}"
                        >

                        {{ __($category->name) }}

                    </label>

                </li>

                <ul class="mt-1 ml-5 flex flex-col gap-1">

                    @foreach ($category->children as $subcategory)

                        <li class="flex items-center gap-2" wire:key="catg-list-{{ $category->id }}">

                            <label class="capitalize">

                                <input type="radio"
                                       wire:model.live="category"
                                       class="accent-purple w-4 h-4"
                                       value="{{ $subcategory->id}}"
                                >

                                {{ __($subcategory->name) }}

                            </label>

                        </li>

                    @endforeach

                </ul>

            @endforeach

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div>

        <p class="capitalize font-semibold">price</p>

        <input type="number"
               wire:model.live.500="min_price"
               placeholder="Min Price"
               class="mt-3 w-full border border-border-white rounded-md p-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-purple "
        >

        @error('min_price')
            <p class="text-sm mt-1 text-red-500">{{ $message}}</p>
        @enderror

        <input type="number"
               wire:model.live.500="max_price"
               placeholder="Max Price"
               class="mt-1 w-full border border-border-white rounded-md p-4 focus:outline-none focus:border-purple"
        >

    </div>

</div>


The class
class Sidebar extends Component
{
    #[Url(except: '')]
    public $type = 'any';

    #[Url(except: '')]
    public $category = '0';

    #[Url, Validate]
    public $min_price = '';

    #[Url]
    public $max_price = '';


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'min_price' => 'numeric|between:1,999999999',
            'max_price' => 'numeric|between:1,999999999',
        ];
    }


    public function render()
    {
        // The main categories are retrieved using the mainCategs() scope, and the children are retrieved using the 'children' relation
        // The *minPrice()* and *maxPrice()* scopes limit the categories by price
        // Note that if a main category is excluded also its children are excluded: if you want to exclude only the children categories you must 
        //   remove the lines of code indicated by (1) and (2)         
         
        $categories = Category::mainCategs()
                              ->with(['children' =>
                                       fn ($q)  => $q->minPrice($this->min_price)
                                                     ->maxPrice($this->max_price)
                               ])
                              ->minPrice($this->min_price)  // (1)
                              ->maxPrice($this->max_price)  // (2) 
                              ->get();

        return view('livewire.listings.sidebar', [
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
}


